# Form API merge persistent variables into array?

Tags: forms

I am trying to merge multiple persistent variables from a Drupal form into one array, which is then the sole variable set in the form using variable_get('sole_array_var', $default).

The problem is that I cannot seem to get the form to equate the $form_state['values] array to the 'sole_array_var' above.

Is there any precedent for not using multiple persistent variables in forms, but rather using one which is saved as an array.  I hope this makes sense, here's an example:

```
function module_settings($form, &$form_state) {
  $default = array(
    'themes' => 0,
    'buttons' => 1,
    'content' => 0,
    'autotext' => 0,
    'autoexpand' => 0,
    'switch' => 0,
    );
$form_settings = array_merge($default, variable_get('mymodules_settings', $default));
$form['mymodules_settings'] = array(
  '#tree' => TRUE,
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('My Module - Options & Settings'),
  '#collapsible' => FALSE,    
);
// Add theme selection.
$form['mymodules_settings']['themes'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Theme'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
);
// Themes.
$form['mymodules_settings']['themes']['theme'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('My Module Theme'),
  '#default_value' => $form_settings['themes']['theme'],
  '#options' => $moduleoptions,
  '#description' => t('Select ....'),
);
// Refine chosen theme.
$form['mymodules_settings']['themes']['pattern'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('Buttons/Arrows'),
  '#default_value' => $form_settings['themes']['pattern'],
  '#description' => t('Turn patterns on or off.'),
);

   return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Comment: Are you showing all the code of that function?

Comment: no it's a summary, it continues as I had at least 15 persistent variables originally, so its very lengthy.

Comment: You should show the rest of the code, leaving out the part for the other form elements, since that is irrelevant. With the rest of the code, I can answer the question.

Comment: OK thanks, I've left out the other elements, and added just the function return/closure

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question completely based on the original wording. It sounds like you just want to set the default values of a form from a serialized array that you're storing as a Drupal variable – is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it, and I expect the behaviour should be the same as a normal #default_value in that it returns the updated values/states when submitted.

Comment: I've been stumped with this for a while and I suspect it has something to do with the nested arrays and #tree but I'm not sure.